How to Use Power Automate to Recursively Read Values in SharePoint?
I've found several articles and how-tos across the interwebs on using Power Automate to recursively read values from SharePoint rows. I haven't come across a scenario that matches mine closely enough that I thought I could adapt its guidance to my situation. And I admit that I am operating at the outer limits of my understanding of working with arrays and attempting recursion in Power Automate. I am hoping that someone can either boil down an approach or recommend a link that matches my case closely enough that I can grasp it and adapt it.
I have a SharePoint list that contains a Choice field that permits multiple values. For each row, the values in that Choice field can be anywhere from zero to multiple entries, and they will match the Title field value for another row in the list, effectively creating a parent-child hierarchy. I would like to recursively read these values into an array so that I can display the hierarchy in summary form at least in a notification email.
For instance, what I will call the "parent" entry, 14J1AirLoad, has three entries in this SharePoint choice field. Each of those entries in turn, potentially, can have references of their own. There is no specific pattern to these relationships. I would not only like to capture all of the entries until, walking down the hierarchy, I have exhausted the tree, but I would like to capture the structure, so that at each level the parent-child nature of the relationship is captured. Functionally, this is very similar to a folder structure, and would result in something similar to this array-like structure:
[
    "14J1AirLoad",
    [
        "14J1FV438Flow",
        [
            "14J1FV438Cg",
            "14J1FC438C1",
            [
                "14J1FV438Dg"
            ],
        ],
        "14J1PV698Flow",
        [
            "14J1PV698Cg",
            "14J1PV698C1",
            [
                "14J1PV698Cv"
            ],
        ],
        "14J1PV711Flow",
        [
            "14J1PV711Cg",
            [
                "14J1PV711C1",
                [
                    "14J1PV711Cv"
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]

To clarify, I'm not insisting that the array structure look like what I've shown here -- that is just to help clarify what I'm talking about.
From a Power Automate perspective, my effort so far has been to create a flow that collects any child values from the parent row and then use a child flow to call each of those child rows to extract any such values from the choice field on them. The two places where I get stuck are:

How do I then integrate those child values into my array while also retaining their parent-child relationship?
How do I then iterate through and recurse the additional rows represented by those new values, returning any further results and integrating them into my array as well?

Thanks.
